# jQuery jScrollPane Custom Styling

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

So, I've been trying to get jScrollPane to work and can't. I feel like a bit of a moron. The website and some fiddles I've seen make it look simple. However, my code doesn't change the styling of the scrollbars at all.

I've added the scripts (there are three in total, the main one and two mouse wheel ones) and the css, still no go.

So I found the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nPXf/34/

(looking for to do same, perhaps keep it normal width though)

And I tried to make it work with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6tUMk/4/

It seems like the following script is what you are supposed to use to trigger things (I created a separate script file with just this in it, leaving the downloaded scripts untouched):

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scrollpane').jScrollPane();
});
```

So, I've added the scrollpane class where I want the scrollbar, but none of the additional styling takes hold like it does in the first fiddle I linked.

I looked through the HTML within some of the jScrollPane demos and I see a lot of additional classes being used, jspScrollable, jspContainer, and others. However, from looking at the working fiddle and documentation within the jScrollPane website, it seems like if you set up the script properly, then any element (in my case, .scrollpane) triggered within the .jScrollPane() script should make it work. But I guess I'm missing something?

So, how does this work? What am I missing here?

Comment: You forgot to add the external resources (js libraries and the css which jscrollpane requires)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the external links to [jquery.jscrollpane.css](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css), [jquery.jscrollpane.min.js](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js), (option) [jquery.mousewheel.js](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/6tUMk/6/)

P.S. Put the content inside `<p></p>` to make it look more pronounced.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? This answer is only partially solved by changing the library from mootools to jQuery. In his fiddle, switching to jQuery and adding the other 4 external sources still does not produce results like the jScrollPane demo.